# Check for running applications on ios using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Is there a way to check background running applications on iOS using Swift 3/2 ?

I tried this solution : [Process.swift](https://github.com/beltex/SystemKit/blob/master/SystemKit/Process.swift)

but its gives me errors related with permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps running are considered as private and you will not have permission to see the list from your app. Only the OS will have permission to access this.

Also apple will reject your app, if you submit an app to store with this code.